# Netbeans: overridable method call in constructor

Tags: java, netbeans

I have the following class.

```
public abstract class MyRoot extends Object {

    public MyRoot () {
        super();
        this.initObj();
    }

    protected abstract void initObj();
}
```

All other classes in project extend this class `MyRoot`. The subclasses put the initialization stuff in `initObj()`.

```
public class MyCard extends MyRoot
{
    public MyCard()
    {
       super();
    }

    private ArrayList<Person> persons;

    @Override
    protected void initObj()
    {
       this.persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
    }
}
```

In class `MyCard` I do all initialization in `initObj()` and everything seems to work. What's wrong with this approach of initializing everything in `initObj()`? Netbeans points to `initObj()` in `MyRoot`'s constructor and warns that I have `overridable method call in constructor`

Comment: So how can I create a common method for subclasses to put the initialization in?

Comment: Have each subclass do their own relevant initialization, in their own constructor.